# Write parquet file to Azure blob storage

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, parquet, pyarrow

I need to test writing a large parquet file to Azure Blob. I currently have a large CSV file in my local disk. I write it to stream using Bytes IO() and write to Azure using blob_client.upload_blob(output, overwrite=True). But this doesn't work well for files that are very large(~10GB). Is there a better way to write parquet to Azure blob storage?

```
import io
import logging
import os
import sys

from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient, BlobClient
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from google.cloud import bigquery

import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# azure credentials
load_dotenv()
tenant = os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
client = os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID']
secret = os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET']
cred = ClientSecretCredential(tenant, client, secret)


# load fake data
spark = (SparkSession
             .builder
             .master('local[1]')
             .appName('filename')
             .getOrCreate())

df = spark.read.csv('file_path.csv')

# write to stream
output = io.BytesIO()
df.to_parquet(output, index=False, engine='pyarrow')
output.seek(0)

# setting up azure storage for writing
containername = 'con'
azure_url = f'https://test.blob.core.windows.net/{containername}'

container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(azure_url, credential=cred)

destination_file_path = '...path/filename.parquet'
blob_client = container.get_blob_client(destination_file_path)


# write to azure
try:
    blob_client.upload_blob(output, overwrite=True)
except Exception as e:
    pass
else:
    print('Success')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is trying to upload the whole file in one go. When uploading large files you will want to upload it in chunks using a process called file chunking. The basic logic for uploading file chunks is:

1. Determine size of file chunk you want to process at a time
2. Read the number of bytes from your size into a buffer
3. Create a block ID to match your upload
4. Upload your buffer to Azure Blob Storage
5. Repeat until done

The Azure storage team has made a couple of code samples available for this scenario (too large to put in this post):

Uploading a large file: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-file/azure/storage/file/_upload_chunking.py

Uploading a large blob: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_upload_chunking.py

Comment: I think you linked to library code, not example code. The parent repository does have a `samples` folder, though